# Customize minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I'm writing my thesis and I woud like to add a minitoc at the beginning of each chapter. However, I don't like the standard format where the titles of the sections are listed as in the main TOC and I would like to align the titles on the same row (a format I saw in several books), maybe sperated by a comma or a textbullet. I mean something like this:

> Chapter 1
>
> Contents
>
> 1.1 Sec 1, 1.2 Sec 2, 1.3 Sec3, 1.4 Sec 4

I can do this for the main TOC through the titletoc package, but I need it for minitoc. Is there a way to have this customization of the minitoc? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would using `titletoc` for the partial ToC (instead of `minitoc`) also be an option?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using `titletoc` for both the main and the partial ToCs; the `titlesec` package was also used so that `\chapter` will start and print its partial ToC automatically:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand\partialtocname{\contentsname}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
  [\vspace*{2pc}\titlerule\vspace*{1pc}%
    \startcontents\vbox{\Large\partialtocname}\vskip1ex
    \printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}\vspace*{1pc}\titlerule]
\titlecontents*{lsection}[0pt]
  {\small\normalfont}{\thecontentslabel\space}{}
  {,~\itshape\thecontentspage}[\space\textbullet\space][.]
\titlecontents*{lsubsection}[0pt]{}{}{}{}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One Two}
\section{Section One Two}
\subsection{Subsection One Two One}
\subsection{Subsection One Two Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\subsection{Subsection One Three One}
\subsection{Subsection One Three Two}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\subsection{Subsection TwoOne One}
\subsection{Subsection Two One Two}
\section{Section Two Two}
\subsection{Subsection Two Two One}
\subsection{Subsection Two Two Two}

\end{document}
```

The main ToC:

[image]

The partial ToCs:

[image]

and

[image]

Of course, your thesis will have some chapters that won't require a partial ToC such as those of the front and backmatter sections (Acknowledgements, Preface, Main ToC, possibly Appendices and the Bibliography). I did a improvement to my initial code defining a boolean to let you easily activate and deactivate the partial ToCs; initially the boolean is set to false, so the frontmatter chapters won't have partial ToCs; once you begin the mainmatter (in fact, whenever you want to start using partal ToCs) all you have to do is to set the boolean to true using `\chapterwithtoctrue`. For the backmatter (or, in general, to deactivate the partial ToCs) all you have to do is to set the boolean to false using `\chapterwithtocfalse`; a complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% The name to be used as title for the partialToCs
% initially set to be equal to \contentsname
\newcommand\partialtocname{\contentsname}
% depending on this boolean, \chapter will create or not a partial ToC
\newif\ifchapterwithtoc
\chapterwithtocfalse

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
  [\ifchapterwithtoc
      \vspace*{2pc}\titlerule\vspace*{1pc}%
      \startcontents\vbox{\Large\partialtocname}\vskip1ex
      \printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}\vspace*{1pc}\titlerule%
    \else\fi%
  ]

\titlecontents*{lsection}[0pt]
  {\small\normalfont}{\thecontentslabel\space}{}
  {,~\itshape\thecontentspage}[\space\textbullet\space][.]
\titlecontents*{lsubsection}[0pt]{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Preface}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapterwithtoctrue

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One Two}
\section{Section One Two}
\subsection{Subsection One Two One}
\subsection{Subsection One Two Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\subsection{Subsection One Three One}
\subsection{Subsection One Three Two}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\subsection{Subsection TwoOne One}
\subsection{Subsection Two One Two}
\section{Section Two Two}
\subsection{Subsection Two Two One}
\subsection{Subsection Two Two Two}

\backmatter
\chapterwithtocfalse

\chapter{Appenix One}
\chapter{Appenix Two}

\end{document}
```

This can be improved even more by appropriately patching (wuth the help of the `etoolbox` package, for example) `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great reply! However I noticed a small problem when I have several subsections. Infact, in this case there seems to be addictional space between the page number and the following textbullet. Moreover the more subsection I have the larger this space seems to be. Is there a way to solve this problem?