# Titletoc and Titlesec in just some chapters

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc, minitoc

I have a `twocolumn` document and I should insert the `minitoc` in the first chapters with `titlesec` and `titletoc`. I read the answer to [Customize minitoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56311/customize-minitoc); however, if I change the `\titleformat` before appendices, all the sections of the appendix chapters will appear within the last `minitoc`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand\partialtocname{\contentsname}
% depending on this boolean, \chapter will create or not a partial ToC
\newif\ifchapterwithtoc
\chapterwithtocfalse

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
  [\ifchapterwithtoc
     \vspace*{2pc}\titlerule\vspace*{1pc}%
     \startcontents\vbox{\Large\partialtocname}\vskip1ex
     \printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}\vspace*{1pc}\titlerule%
   \else\fi%
  ]

\titlecontents*{lsection}[0pt]
{\small\normalfont}{\thecontentslabel\space}{}
{,~\itshape\thecontentspage}[\space\textbullet\space][.]
\titlecontents*{lsubsection}[0pt]{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Preface}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapterwithtoctrue

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\appendix
\chapterwithtocfalse

\chapter{Appenix One}
\section{Section A One}
\section{Section A Two}
\chapter{Appenix Two}
\section{Section B One}
\section{Section B Two}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) No need to add thanks and signature to the post. Your user badge is automatically included in th epost and to thank any help, simply upvote any good answewr you may receive. This keeps our posts shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To copy here what I already answered you your crosspost [Switching off titletoc for some chapters](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22747) on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/) - you could use `\stopcontents` at the beginning of the appendix to prevent that the appendix sections would appear in the last minitoc:

```
\appendix
\chapterwithtocfalse
\stopcontents
```

`\startcontents` already stops the previous partial content, however to finally stop you need an explicit `\stopcontents` here.