# Create a "continuous" minitoc at the beginning of each chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I am required to have, at the beginning of each chapter of my thesis and just after chapter number/name, something like this (*e.g.* for Chapter 1):

> Table of contents: 1.1 chapter1section1name 1.2 chapter1section2name 1.3 chapter1section3name 1.4 chapter1section4name 1.5 chapter1section5name 1.6 chapter1section6name

That is, a minitoc but without going to a new line for each entry.
What's the best way to achieve this result? I really have no clue...

Comment: The best way to start is to supply the community with a minimal example that sets up a representable version of your document layout. That way we can see which packages you are already using (which might conflict with a possible solution) and not have to recreate this from scratch. Help the community to help you.

Comment: You can try the `etoc` package.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! In the end, I solved thanks to this beautiful piece of code: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56311/customize-minitoc?rq=1

Indeed, I don't know if this question should be marked as a duplicate of the linked one.

Comment: for the record, there are some examples in the [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) manual: at end of 31.7, using enumitem `itemize*` environment and also the one in 22. A (crazy) inline display, which even goes to render subsections as footnotes... there is an attachment icon at top of page 35 where you can get the code without losing indentation on double-clicking (with Adobe Reader).